# Как лучше создать список текстовых данных для их последующего отражения в динамических таблицах на сайте

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, база-данных, xml

Как лучше сделать динамическое формирование таблиц на страницах сайта?

1. Есть список оказываемых услуг по разным направлениям и их стоимость.
2. Есть разные раздела сайта и страницы, соответствующие этим направлениям, на которых должны отражаться определенные услуги из названного списка с возможностью пользовательского выбора (checkbox).
3. Набор услуг и их стоимость могут меняться время от времени.
4. CMS - Joomla 3x

Comment: добавте в таблицу поле service_type и пусть это поле хранит значения 1, 2, 3 ...
Каждое значение, это та или иная услуга. После чего вы сможете выберать стоки для требуемой услуги. Если я правильно понял

Comment: @dakiesse спасибо, но не совсем правильно: список услуг должен быть во внешнем источнике, который можно легко редактировать. А таблицы на страницах сайта формироваться динамически из этого источника. Насколько я понимаю в источнике, конечно, должен быть идентификатор вида услуг. Но, так как я не специалист в php и jg - не пойму  как связать источник (и какой он должен быть) со страницами

Comment: так речь и шла об внешнем источнике, создайте таблицу в базе данных с необходимыми полями, включая поле service_type. Далее прочтите документацию по joomle, как обращаться к базе данных и делать выборки, и выведи все это в html вам нужный.

Comment: спасибо, попробую разобраться